# Tomcat 7 ClassNotFoundException:org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer

Tags: java, rest, glassfish, jersey, tomcat7

I am attempting to run a RESTful service from apache 7.0.57 on OS X 10.10 with Jersey 2.13, JDK 8. I have deployed Apache and it starts ok. I have written a simple RESTful service and deployed it to the WEB-INF/classes. The web.xml is configured. However, when I attempt to start the tomcat the restful resource errors with the following error

```
SEVERE: Servlet /resttest threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer

at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5518)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1245)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1895)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>TestREST</display-name>
 
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>    
         <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>org.sample.resources</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**java class**

> ```
> package org.sample.resources;
>
> import javax.ws.rs.Path;
> import javax.ws.rs.GET;
> import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
> import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
>
> @Path("/xyz")
> public class TestGet {
>
>   @GET
>   @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
>   public String sayHello() {
>       return "Hello Jersey";
>   }
> }
> ```

I have even extracted the contents of the jersey-container-servlet-core.jar to the WEB-INF/classes directory but on restart I still get the same error.

Any pointers?

Answer (score -1):

In Explorer manually copy all the Jersey jar files to WEB-INF/lib; I did this when I had the same problem and that worked for me.